# Rubycas-server character encoding issue (Internal server error)

Tags: rubycas

Since a couple of months ago we are using in production environment a rubycass-server 1.0 validating against Active directory (Microsoft 2008 r2 server). We are using ruby 1.9.2p180, sinatra-1.1.3...  We are having problems with Spanish and Catalan languages. If a user types ñ or ç … in the login or password field when he sends the form it produces an “internal server error” message. I have activated the debug mode in the config.yml options but when this error rises it does not appear any hint into the log file. A couple of days ago I tried the last version of rubycas 1.1.0 and this error (Internal server..) didn’t happen but if the login/password had any of this characters the validation always failed with the message “password incorrect”. I think it is an encoding error.

Has anybody found a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Problem was caused because we were using an old version of net-ldap (0.1.1). I updated this gem to the last version (0.3.1) and works like a charm.